# Xamarin.Form Failed Adding New XAML Pages

Tags: c#, forms, file, xaml, xamarin

I'm new in Xamarin. I want to create XAML Page.But VS create difference file.I don't know what mistake that I do.Hope you guys can help me solve this problem.Thank you in advance.

*Create new XAML Page,Car.xaml*
[image: Create new XAML Page]

but visual studio generated Car.xaml.cs file.Why?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like bug and/or the *Nested File* issue

You could try

1. Deleting the class and restarting Visual Studio and add again
2. Make sure your Visual studio is up to date, and you are using the latest version of *Xamarin.Forms*

Comment: I have to uninstall vs and all the other.Re-install back and updated.Its worked! Thanks. Appreciate your help sir.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it by creating the project again in another way, instead of using "Shared project" using "NET Standard" and it works perfectly for me.

With "Shared Project" and with Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.6.6, it does not work

[Use Net Standard option to create the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Vi3.jpg)